# Creating unique row IDs in SQL using partition

Tags: sql, sql-server, partition

I'm hoping that someone can either tell me where my syntax is wrong or let me know if there's a better way to achieve my goal. I have taken a large dataset and applied a number of identifying fields to later group the data by. I would like to apply a unique 'Cohort ID' to the data that I can use to later group the data by. I was thinking that a Row_Number() Over (Partition) type of structure would work but it clearly isn't for some reason. I am getting Cohort IDs that are different for my specified fields when they should be the same. My code is below:

To further specify what I am trying to do, if all items in my selected fields below are equal for two different rows of data, I want that to be labeled with the same Cohort ID. If the next row is the same as the first two except for a different 'Issuer', for example, I want that to get a different Cohort ID.

Data sample below with my expected Cohort ID

```
Asset_Type  Account Issuer  Return_Bucket   Age_Bucket  Type_Bucket Risk_Bucket Cohort ID
Equity  Client 1    Bank A  10-15   3-6 months  Financial   Moderate    1
Equity  Client 1    Bank A  10-15   3-6 months  Financial   Moderate    1
Equity  Client 1    Bank A  10-15   6-12 months Financial   Moderate    2
Equity  Client 1    Bank A  10-15   6-12 months Financial   Moderate    2
Equity  Client 1    Bank A  10-15   6-12 months Financial   High    3
Fixed   Client 1    Bank A  10-15   6-12 months Financial   High    4
Equity  Client 1    Bank A  5-10    3-6 months  Financial   Moderate    5



Select
Row_Number() Over(Partition By [Asset_Type],
[Account],
[Issuer],
[Return_Bucket],
[Age_Bucket],
[Type_Bucket],
[Risk_Bucket]
Order by [Account]) Account AS CohortID
into Test_Table_2
from Test_Table_1
```

Comment: Sample data and expected result please.

Comment: Sql server? Check out `CHECKSUM` or `BINARY_CHECKSUM`

Comment: I am assuming SQL Server based on the syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sample results suggest that you want `dense_rank()` -- no gaps:

```
Select t.*
       dense_rank() Over (order by [Asset_Type], [Account], [Issuer], [Return_Bucket],
                                   [Age_Bucket], [Type_Bucket], [Risk_Bucket]
                         ) as CohortID
into Test_Table_2
from Test_Table_1 t;
```

The `partition by` splits the counting into different groups. That means that `1` will be repeated in each group.  The `order by` simply orders them.

I assume that you have other columns as well.  Duplicates in tables is generally not very useful.  I would recommend instead that you remove them.

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly and tied out to the number of records created in my bigger and bulkier group by statement.

Comment: Now one final question; how can I add this field to an existing table? I get errors saying that windowed functions can only appear in the Select or order by Clauses.

Comment: @financedude . . . Your code is using `select into`.  It gets added into the temporary table you have defined.  If you want to modify *an existing table*, then you would have a different question.

Comment: I want to do the same thing, but now I'm trying to do it so that the ranked CohortID field is permanently added to my original table so that I can use it in group by clauses later. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

YOu can use RANK and do not need the partition:

```
Select *,
Rank() Over(ORDER By [Asset_Type],
[Account],
[Issuer],
[Return_Bucket],
[Age_Bucket],
[Type_Bucket],
[Risk_Bucket]) AS CohortID
into Test_Table_2
from Test_Table_1
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `DENSE_RANK` instead?

Comment: Dense Rank is correct however, the ordering needs to be expanded for this to work.

Comment: Yes, should be DENSE_RANK if no gaps are required